# Is there any method like 「scaler.inverse_transform()」to get partial scaler params to de-normalize the answer？

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, data-science

I am trying to normalize my data(with shape **(23687,7)**), then I save the mean and std of the original dataset to **"normalized_param.pkl"**

After fitting the normalized data to my LSTM model, I will get an answer array (with shape **(23687, 1)**)

Now what I gonna do is：

```
test_sc_path = os.path.join('normalized_standard', 'normalized_param.pkl')
test_scaler = load(test_sc_path)
test_denorm_value = test_scaler.inverse_transform(test_normalized_data)
```

> ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (23687,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (23687,7)

---

I think that's because the **test_scaler** object have 7 dim params inside, so if I want to de-normalize only 1 dim data, I should use
`test_scaler.mean_[-1]`and`「test_scaler.scale_[-1]`to get the last param I want to compute.
However, I think it's quite complicated, is there any sklearn method just like `scaler.inverse_transform()` I can easily use to solve this problem？

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a method for it. See the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

scaler.fit(data) # Basically fits the data, store means & standard deviations.
scaler.transform(data) # Standardize (Normalize) the data with the scaler parameters
scaler.fit_transform(data) # Fits & Transform 
scaler.inverse_transform(data) # Apply inverse transformation for the input data.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's not exactly what I want to ask.
I know the method you mentioned.
In my case, my input_data have 7 attributes, but my predict_data(output) only have 1 attributes. So when I normalize the training data and save the `StandardScaler()` , it actually saves 7 attributes.
In the other process, I load `StandardScaler()` and  normalize the test_data. After fit it to the model, I will get the prediction which only have 1 attributes.
Now, I want to de-normalize the prediction, I can not use `scaler.fit_transform(data)` directly since the method should fit 7 attributes.

Comment: I see, let's seperate X (predictors) and y (target), now scale X and y seperately with `StandardScaler()` then if you apply `inverse_transform` with "scaler for y", it should do it. Basically, if target varaible, y, is among the 7 attributes, split it.